# Debugging DNS resolutions in kubernetes

Tags: docker, ubuntu, kubernetes, dns, coredns

I have initialized kubernetes v1.13.1 cluster on `Ubuntu 16.04` using below command:

```
sudo kubeadm init --token-ttl=0 --apiserver-advertise-address=192.168.88.142
```

and installed `weave` using:

```
kubectl apply -f "https://cloud.weave.works/k8s/net?k8s-version=$(kubectl version | base64 | tr -d '\n')"
```

I have 10 `raspberry pi` acting as worker nodes and connected to the cluster. All of them are running the deployment fine. There nodes are running pods which try to connect to iot hub `visdwk-azure-devices.net` and publish some data. Out of 10 nodes, only few nodes are able to connect and other throws error `unable to connect to iot hub`. I did a ping test and found out that they were not able to ping google while they were pinging the public IP address of google.

This made me think that something is wrong with the `coredns` pod. I followed this [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/) and did below test.

Pod has below contents in `/etc/resolv.conf`

```
nameserver 10.96.0.10
search visdwk.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local
options ndots:5
```

which looks normal to me. All the coredns pods are running fine.

```
coredns-86c58d9df4-42xqc               1/1     Running   8         1d11h
coredns-86c58d9df4-p6d98               1/1     Running   7         1d6h
```

I have also done `nslookup kubernetes.default` from the busybox container and got the proper response. Below are the logs of `coredns-86c58d9df4-42xqc`

```
.:53
2019-02-08T08:40:10.038Z [INFO] CoreDNS-1.2.6
2019-02-08T08:40:10.039Z [INFO] linux/amd64, go1.11.2, 756749c
CoreDNS-1.2.6
linux/amd64, go1.11.2, 756749c
 [INFO] plugin/reload: Running configuration MD5 = 
f65c4821c8a9b7b5eb30fa4fbc167769
t
```

Above logs also looks normal.

I can also not say that the pod is not able to resolve the iot hub because of any error from weave because if weave is throwing error then I believe the pod will never start and will always be in failed state but in actual the pod remains in running state. Please correct me here if I am wrong.

DNS service also seems to be in running state:

```
NAME                   TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)         AGE
kube-dns               ClusterIP   10.96.0.10     <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP   1d6h
```

But still I am not able to figure out as to why few nodes in the cluster are not able to resolve the iot hub. Can anyone please give me some suggestions here. Please help. Thanks.

Logs from failed pod:

```
 1550138544: New connection from 127.0.0.1 on port 1883.
1550138544: New client connected from 127.0.0.1 as 6f1e2c4f-c44d-4c27-b9a9-0fb91f816504 (c1, k60).
1550138544: Sending CONNACK to 6f1e2c4f-c44d-4c27-b9a9-0fb91f816504 (0, 0)
1550138544: Received PUBLISH from 6f1e2c4f-c44d-4c27-b9a9-0fb91f816504 (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'devices/machine6/messages/events/', ... (1211 bytes))
1550138544: Received DISCONNECT from 6f1e2c4f-c44d-4c27-b9a9-0fb91f816504
1550138544: Client 6f1e2c4f-c44d-4c27-b9a9-0fb91f816504 disconnected.
1550138547: Saving in-memory database to /mqtt/data/mosquitto.db.
1550138547: Bridge local.machine6 doing local SUBSCRIBE on topic devices/machine6/messages/events/#
1550138547: Connecting bridge iothub-bridge (visdwk.azure-devices.net:8883)
1550138552: Error creating bridge: Try again.
1550138566: New connection from 127.0.0.1 on port 1883.
1550138566: New client connected from 127.0.0.1 as afb6cc2a-ee78-482e-aff0-fc595e06f86a (c1, k60).
1550138566: Sending CONNACK to afb6cc2a-ee78-482e-aff0-fc595e06f86a (0, 0)
1550138566: Received PUBLISH from afb6cc2a-ee78-482e-aff0-fc595e06f86a (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'devices/machine6/messages/events/', ... (1211 bytes))
1550138566: Received DISCONNECT from afb6cc2a-ee78-482e-aff0-fc595e06f86a
1550138566: Client afb6cc2a-ee78-482e-aff0-fc595e06f86a disconnected.
1550138567: New connection from 127.0.0.1 on port 1883.
1550138567: New client connected from 127.0.0.1 as 01b9e135-fbc8-4d67-9962-356e8cf9f080 (c1, k60).
1550138567: Sending CONNACK to 01b9e135-fbc8-4d67-9962-356e8cf9f080 (0, 0)
1550138567: Received PUBLISH from 01b9e135-fbc8-4d67-9962-356e8cf9f080 (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'devices/machine6/messages/events/', ... (755 bytes))
1550138567: Received DISCONNECT from 01b9e135-fbc8-4d67-9962-356e8cf9f080
1550138567: Client 01b9e135-fbc8-4d67-9962-356e8cf9f080 disconnected.
1550138578: Saving in-memory database to /mqtt/data/mosquitto.db.
1550138583: Bridge local.machine6 doing local SUBSCRIBE on topic devices/machine6/messages/events/#
1550138583: Connecting bridge iothub-bridge (visdwk.azure-devices.net:8883)
1550138588: Error creating bridge: Try again.
```

Pod is running a mosquitto container which try to connect to `visdwk.azure-devices.net` and throws error.

```
Connecting bridge iothub-bridge (visdwk.azure-devices.net:8883)
Error creating bridge: Try again.
```

Comment: Can you share CoreDNS configmap from the affected Nodes?

Comment: @mk_sta I can share the CoreDNS config map of Master by running `kubectl edit cm coredns -n kube-system` but I am not sure if I can run the same command on affected node. Can you please tell me how can I get the configmap. Thanks

Comment: Did you have a look at the coreDNS logs when trying to resolve IP addresses on a failing worker node? Plus, check if all nodes have the same content on the /etc/resolv.conf file. Finally, check if on failing nodes you can ping the DNS address (10.69.0.10).

Comment: @whites11 1. If I try to resolve the IP address on failing worker node and monitor the logs of coreDNS, I do not see anything. Logs show the same content which I have included in the question. 2. Yes I can confirm that all the nodes have same content in `/etc/resolv.conf`. 3. I am not able to ping `10.96.0.10` from the failing node as well as working nodes. Looks like this is the issue.?

Comment: Yeah, looks like an overlay network issue to me then.

Comment: @whites11 Can you please explain a bit more about overlay network issue. How can I resolve it.

Comment: The overlay network is a software component present in any kubernetes cluster that allows nodes to be part of the same virtual private network and communicate each other. In your case you mentioned you are using `weave`. You should check if every node is correctly running the weave pod and check its logs on failing nodes to find out if that could be the reason for your issue.

Comment: @S Andrew, you can check CoreDNS configmap via command: `kubectl get cm coredns -n kube-system -o yaml`.

Comment: @mk_sta Do you want me to run this on worker or master node.?

Comment: @S Andrew, I think it's a good time to compare configmap on master and workers, and then you can output the result.

Comment: @mk_sta I am not able to run this command on worker.

Comment: @S Andrew, Can you check whether your CoreDNS Pod can receive any request by adding `log` parameter in particular configmap, as describe [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/#are-dns-queries-being-received-processed)?

Comment: @mk_sta Thanks. After including log in coredns configmap, I can see this line `visdwk.azure-devices.net.visdwknamespace.svc.cluster.local. udp 82 false 512" NXDOMAIN qr,aa,rd,ra 175 0.000651078s` where `visdwk.azure-devices.net` is the Iot hub name. But not able to understand what this log means.?

Comment: @S Andrew, This error means that domain name is not recognized, or does not exist, Do you have such service: `visdwk.azure-devices.net.visdwknamespace.svc.cluster.local` in your cluster?

Comment: @mk_sta I do not have such service. This `visdwk.azure-devices.net` is the Iot hub name which nodes try to connect but fails and `visdwknamespace` is the namespace I am using for my kubernetes.

Comment: @S Andrew so is the overlay network working?

Comment: can you share the logs from pod that is trying to connect iot hub. share the logs from working pod and failed pod

Comment: @PEkambaram which logs? `weave` or `coredns`?

Comment: logs from the pod that is failing to connect visdwk-azure-devices.net

Comment: @PEkambaram I have updated the question with logs from failed pod

Comment: can you confirm that firewalld service is stopped and disabled on all the nodes.

Comment: share the output from the command ( sudo iptables-save | grep 8883 ) from two nodes (from node where you can hit the iot service  and second node where the connection is failing).

Comment: @PEkambaram I am using `raspberry pi` as worker node and by default there is no firewall configured on it. When I run `sudo iptables-save | grep 8883` on both (failing and running node), I didnt get anything.

Comment: This seems to be related to your issue: https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/issues/840

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that one of your DNS Pods is not providing DNS services.

The evidence is is in the statement that "only few nodes are able to connect and other throws error unable to connect to iot hub"

This is a classic symptom of load-balancing with a failed node in the loop.

Try:

1. Remove the DNS server pod that gave the message: `visdwk.azure-devices.net.visdwknamespace.svc.cluster.local. udp 82 false 512" NXDOMAIN qr,aa,rd,ra 175 0.000651078s where visdwk.azure-devices.net`
2. Wait for the changes to propagate through the cluster.
3. Test the connections.

If this is correct they should all connect.

To confirm, add the pod back and remove the other one. Retest, they should all fail to connect.

Comment: Thank You. Then what should I do for failed pods.? I cannot remove them from the cluster permanently.

Comment: Verify the configuration of the pod.  Did the test prove successful?

Comment: I am testing it and will update. Just wanted to know, could this be because of low network connection, as I am getting very high response time (~1150ms) while pinging some nodes.?

Comment: Probably not, the error message shows the DNS packet was received, and sent a non-existant domain, `NXDOMAIN` response.

Comment: Did the test prove successful?